# How to skip reading the file header in hadoop mapreduce

Tags: hadoop

I am learning hadoop mapreduce using java,I have a sample file with data as below, how do I skip processing the header line in this file..because when I see the mapper input, it is considering the header also..

roll no|school name|name|age|Gender|class|subject|marks

1|xyz|pqr|abc|10|M|1|science|98

Comment: What is the file format you are using for this data ?

Comment: The best solution would be to write a custom `InputFormat` that discards the first line of each file.

Comment: The file format I am using is a .txt file, and how to create custom InputFormat, could you please show an example

Answer (score 1):

Because you already know what header looks like, you can just skip the header. This approach makes the application more slower.

```
@Override
public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, OutputCollector<Text, Text> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException{
      String[] row = value.toString();

      if( row.equals( "roll no|school name|name|age|Gender|class|subject|marks") )
            return;

      //NOW YOU ARE HEADER FREE 
      //do some operations depending on your needs..

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are running with single mapper, you can use the counter in an if condition. If you are running more than one mapper, check for header string in an if condition.